# Should AggregateService be used as a container to store common dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a base controller class which uses aggregate services in autofac to inject its dependencies. In a class derived from base controller, I need to access a service which is a part of aggregate container. Which one is a better way?

```
public Interface ICommonControllerDependencies
{
    ICookieService CookieService{ get; }
    IAuthenticationService AuthenticationService{ get; }
}

public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ICommonControllerDependencies Dependencies;

    protected BaseController(ICommonControllerDependencies dependencies)
    {
        this.Dependencies = dependencies;
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData[UserName] = Dependencies.AuthenticationService.UserName;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);            
    }
     protected ActionResult RedirectToDefaultPage()
    {
        var page = Dependencies.CookieService.GetDefaultPageCookie(Request, RouteData);
        //Do Something
    }  

}

public class BaseReportController : BaseController
{
    public BaseReportController(ICommonControllerDependencies dependencies)
        : base(dependencies)
   {
        _cookieService = dependencies.CookieService;
   }
}
```

OR

```
public class BaseReportController : BaseController
{
    public BaseReportController(
        ICookieService cookieService, 
        ICommonControllerDependencies dependencies)
        : base(dependencies)
    {
        _cookieService = cookieService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what those common dependencies really are, instead of calling them `IServiceA` and `IServiceB`. I suspect you are violating the Single Responsiblity principle here and like to give feedback on that. Perhaps you can give an example of how the controller uses these dependencies as well.

Comment: Besides, this is not an Aggregate or Facade Service, but just a bunch of dependencies grouped together in a container and accessible as public properties. An Facade Service actually uses those dependencies itself and doesn't expose them to the outside.

Comment: I am calling it AggregateService by looking at the example [link](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AggregateService). I have updated the code with the names of the services as well. I want to set viewData with certain values using these services before executing any action from controller. Please explain the principle, I am violating here.

Answer (score 2):

The [`AggregateService`](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AggregateService) is intended to be what isolates your subclass from changes in the super class, and enable changes in the superclass without breaking subclasses.
If you go for option 1, you couple the subclass to your superclass, thus loosing the intended isolation.

Without knowing more about your design I would go for option 2. I don't think that I can anticipate `ServiceA` to always be there. Taking an explicit dependency on `IServiceA` in the subclass, that class can live on happily ignorant about changes going on in the superclass internals.

Comment: If option 2 is the correct way, then won't that be the case with AggregateService always? In a way, if any service that is a part of AggregateService needs to be injected in any of the subclass, one should keep it independent with the AggregateService object. Can you tell me the cases where one should use option 1 ?

Comment: Yes, as I designed `AggregateService`, option 2 is the use case for an  AggregateService object. Option 1 is dangerously close to the ServiceLocator pattern, and the coupling introduced will lead to problems down the road. The only case I would allow myself the coupling in option 1 is when I have two or more superclass levels in which operation is tightly bound to each other. But at the "consumer/subclass" level of this hierarchy I would not couple code to the AggregateService.

Answer (score 1):

When you need an Aggregate Service (as the Autofac documentation calls it), this could be a sign of violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), that states that a class should do one thing, and only one thing.

In other words, the Aggregate Service pattern is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)*.

Having [big base classes is a code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) as well, since base classes tend to grow and grow to big and complicated classes, that contain a lot of code that not all sub types use. Instead, the general advice is to favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

With UI frameworks such as ASP.NET MVC however, this is not always easy, since most frameworks themselves promote inheritance.

Try to extract the logic of the base class to separate dependencies, especially when that code in the base class isn't used by all sub types. For instance, you might be able to refactor the `RedirectToDefaultPage` method to the following:

```
public class DefaultPageRedirector
{
    private readonly ICookieService cookieService;

    public DefaultPageRedirector(ICookieService cookieService)
    {
        this.cookieService = cookieService;
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectToDefaultPage(
        Controller controller)
    {
        var page = this.cookieService.GetDefaultPageCookie(
            controller.Request, controller.RouteData);

        //Do Something
    }
}
```

This way you can inject the `DefaultPageRedirector` only into `Controller` types that actually need it.

For the `OnActionExecuting` it is different, since it gets called for each and every sub type. However, the `ViewData["UserName"]` property will probably not be used by every `View` in the system and in that case you should consider returning the `UserName` as part of the (staticly typed) `ViewModel` object. If it is used by most views, you might want to consider using a partial view, because you might have some repetitive code in your views (The [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle holds not only for code, but for every part in the system).

This will probably get rid of most code in the base class, which probably also removes most of the dependencies in the base (if not all).

<sup>* Note that a code smell doesn't mean there is *always* a problem. To quote Wikipedia: "code smell is any symptom in the source code of a program that **possibly indicates** a deeper problem."</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it depends on whether you have IserviceA registered in the container or not and how you anticipate your design evolving.

Personally, I would go with the first option if you don't anticipate removing serviceA from the ICommonControllerDependencies interface. It just seems simpler to inject a single interface.  If you think that you may remove serviceA at some time, I would consider going with the second option as it removes the coupling between the service and the controller dependencies within the BaseReportController. I think the second option more closely follows the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).